# Implement metafizzy isotope with css grid

Tags: jquery-isotope

I am trying to configure metafizzy's isotope plugin to work with css grids but it results in a scattered layout. Here is a snippet demonstrating this behavior.

I have tried changing the layout to masonry but it still doesn't work. However it appears that it works when I default to the example that was given in the documentation but my use case requires that I use css grids. Isn't there a way of getting this to work with css grid.

```js
// external js: isotope.pkgd.js

// init Isotope
var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.element-item'
});
// filter functions
var filterFns = {
  // show if number is greater than 50
  numberGreaterThan50: function() {
    var number = $(this).find('.number').text();
    return parseInt( number, 10 ) > 50;
  },
  // show if name ends with -ium
  ium: function() {
    var name = $(this).find('.name').text();
    return name.match( /ium$/ );
  }
};
// bind filter button click
$('.filters-button-group').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
  var filterValue = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
  // use filterFn if matches value
  filterValue = filterFns[ filterValue ] || filterValue;
  $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
});
// change is-checked class on buttons
$('.button-group').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
  var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
  $buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'button', function() {
    $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
    $( this ).addClass('is-checked');
  });
});
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

/* ---- button ---- */

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: #EEE;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to bottom, hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0), hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.2) );
  color: #222;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #8CF;
  text-shadow: 0 1px hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.5);
  color: #222;
}

.button:active,
.button.is-checked {
  background-color: #28F;
}

.button.is-checked {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.8);
}

.button:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 10px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.8);
}

/* ---- button-group ---- */

.button-group:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.button-group .button {
  float: left;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 1px;
}

.button-group .button:first-child { border-radius: 0.5em 0 0 0.5em; }
.button-group .button:last-child { border-radius: 0 0.5em 0.5em 0; }

/* ---- isotope ---- */

.grid {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(7,1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 'c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7';
    grid-gap: 0 8px;
}

.grid .c1 {
  grid-area: c1;
}

.grid .c2 {
  grid-area: c2;
}

.grid .c3 {
  grid-area: c3;
}

.grid .c4 {
  grid-area: c4;
}

.grid .c5 {
  grid-area: c5;
}

.grid .c6 {
  grid-area: c6;
}

.grid .c7 {
  grid-area: c7;
}

/* clear fix */
.grid:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

/* ---- .element-item ---- */

.element-item {
  position: relative;
/*   float: left; */
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #888;
  color: #262524;
}

.element-item > * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.element-item .name {
  position: absolute;

  left: 10px;
  top: 60px;
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.element-item .symbol {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 0px;
  font-size: 42px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

.element-item .number {
  position: absolute;
  right: 8px;
  top: 5px;
}

.element-item .weight {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 76px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.element-item.alkali          { background: #F00; background: hsl(   0, 100%, 50%); }
.element-item.alkaline-earth  { background: #F80; background: hsl(  36, 100%, 50%); }
.element-item.lanthanoid      { background: #FF0; background: hsl(  72, 100%, 50%); }
.element-item.actinoid        { background: #0F0; background: hsl( 108, 100%, 50%); }
.element-item.transition      { background: #0F8; background: hsl( 144, 100%, 50%); }
.element-item.post-transition { background: #0FF; background: hsl( 180, 100%, 50%); }
.element-item.metalloid       { background: #08F; background: hsl( 216, 100%, 50%); }
.element-item.diatomic        { background: #00F; background: hsl( 252, 100%, 50%); }
.element-item.halogen         { background: #F0F; background: hsl( 288, 100%, 50%); }
.element-item.noble-gas       { background: #F08; background: hsl( 324, 100%, 50%); }
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//npmcdn.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.js"></script>
<h1>Isotope - filtering</h1>

<div class="button-group filters-button-group">
  <button class="button is-checked" data-filter="*">show all</button>
  <button class="button" data-filter=".metal">metal</button>
  <button class="button" data-filter=".transition">transition</button>
  <button class="button" data-filter=".alkali, .alkaline-earth">alkali and alkaline-earth</button>
  <button class="button" data-filter=":not(.transition)">not transition</button>
  <button class="button" data-filter=".metal:not(.transition)">metal but not transition</button>
  <button class="button" data-filter="numberGreaterThan50">number > 50</button>
  <button class="button" data-filter="ium">name ends with &ndash;ium</button>
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="c1 element-item transition metal " data-category="transition">
    <h3 class="name">Mercury</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Hg</p>
    <p class="number">80</p>
    <p class="weight">200.59</p>
  </div>
  <div class="c2 element-item metalloid " data-category="metalloid">
    <h3 class="name">Tellurium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Te</p>
    <p class="number">52</p>
    <p class="weight">127.6</p>
  </div>
  <div class="c3 element-item post-transition metal " data-category="post-transition">
    <h3 class="name">Bismuth</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Bi</p>
    <p class="number">83</p>
    <p class="weight">208.980</p>
  </div>
  <div class="c4 element-item post-transition metal " data-category="post-transition">
    <h3 class="name">Lead</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Pb</p>
    <p class="number">82</p>
    <p class="weight">207.2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="c5 element-item transition metal " data-category="transition">
    <h3 class="name">Gold</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Au</p>
    <p class="number">79</p>
    <p class="weight">196.967</p>
  </div>
  <div class="c6 element-item alkali metal " data-category="alkali">
    <h3 class="name">Potassium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">K</p>
    <p class="number">19</p>
    <p class="weight">39.0983</p>
  </div>
  <div class="c7 element-item alkali metal " data-category="alkali">
    <h3 class="name">Sodium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Na</p>
    <p class="number">11</p>
    <p class="weight">22.99</p>
  </div>
  <div class="c1 element-item transition metal " data-category="transition">
    <h3 class="name">Cadmium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Cd</p>
    <p class="number">48</p>
    <p class="weight">112.411</p>
  </div>
  <div class="c2 element-item alkaline-earth metal " data-category="alkaline-earth">
    <h3 class="name">Calcium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Ca</p>
    <p class="number">20</p>
    <p class="weight">40.078</p>
  </div>
  <div class="c3 element-item transition metal " data-category="transition">
    <h3 class="name">Rhenium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Re</p>
    <p class="number">75</p>
    <p class="weight">186.207</p>
  </div>
  <div class="c4 element-item post-transition metal " data-category="post-transition">
    <h3 class="name">Thallium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Tl</p>
    <p class="number">81</p>
    <p class="weight">204.383</p>
  </div>
  <div class="c5 element-item metalloid " data-category="metalloid">
    <h3 class="name">Antimony</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Sb</p>
    <p class="number">51</p>
    <p class="weight">121.76</p>
  </div>
  <div class="c6 element-item transition metal " data-category="transition">
    <h3 class="name">Cobalt</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Co</p>
    <p class="number">27</p>
    <p class="weight">58.933</p>
  </div>
  <div class="c7 element-item lanthanoid metal inner-transition " data-category="lanthanoid">
    <h3 class="name">Ytterbium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Yb</p>
    <p class="number">70</p>
    <p class="weight">173.054</p>
  </div>
  <div class="c1 element-item noble-gas nonmetal " data-category="noble-gas">
    <h3 class="name">Argon</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Ar</p>
    <p class="number">18</p>
    <p class="weight">39.948</p>
  </div>
  <div class="c2 element-item diatomic nonmetal " data-category="diatomic">
    <h3 class="name">Nitrogen</h3>
    <p class="symbol">N</p>
    <p class="number">7</p>
    <p class="weight">14.007</p>
  </div>
  <div class="c3 element-item actinoid metal inner-transition " data-category="actinoid">
    <h3 class="name">Uranium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">U</p>
    <p class="number">92</p>
    <p class="weight">238.029</p>
  </div>
  <div class="c4 element-item actinoid metal inner-transition " data-category="actinoid">
    <h3 class="name">Plutonium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Pu</p>
    <p class="number">94</p>
    <p class="weight">(244)</p>
  </div>
</div>
```